# how to nest structured filtered queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to build large nested queries (they will be large but rather simple) and I keep on getting errors  when nesting them. I tried several variations (based on the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html)) and the error which I get is usually `filter malformed, no field after start_object`.

The query i want to build is a boolean compound:

- several fields with an `AND`
- and many of the above concatenated with an `OR`

The example data I use:

```
{'N_timeend_epoch': 10, 'N_marker': True, 'N_hostip': 'A'}
{'N_timeend_epoch': 10, 'N_marker': True, 'N_hostip': 'B'}
{'N_timeend_epoch': 11, 'N_marker': True, 'N_hostip': 'A'}
{'N_timeend_epoch': 11, 'N_marker': True, 'N_hostip': 'B'}
{'N_timeend_epoch': 10, 'N_marker': False, 'N_hostip': 'A'}
{'N_timeend_epoch': 11, 'N_marker': False, 'N_hostip': 'B'}
{'N_timeend_epoch': 11, 'N_marker': False, 'N_hostip': 'B'}
```

They are correctly loaded to elasticsearch:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/yop/_search?pretty
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 7,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "yop",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "AUpEErMEPK-TLWy_CSAU",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"N_hostip": "A", "N_timeend_epoch": 10, "N_marker": true}
    }, {
      "_index" : "yop",
      "_type" : "document",
      "_id" : "AUpEErMEPK-TLWy_CSAZ",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"N_hostip": "B", "N_timeend_epoch": 11, "N_marker": false}
    }, 
    (...)
```

I am looking at entries which have a specific `N_timeend_epoch` AND `N_hostip`. The code below buolds the search query:

```
import requests

list_markers = list()

for N_hostip, N_timeend_epoch in [("A", 10), ("B", 10)]:
    list_markers.append(
        {
            "query":
             {
                 "filtered":
                     {
                         "filter":
                             {
                                "bool":
                                    {
                                        "must":
                                            [
                                                {"N_hostip": N_hostip},
                                                {'N_timeend_epoch': N_timeend_epoch}
                                            ]
                                    }
                        }
                     }
             }
        }
    )

q = {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": { "bool": { "should": list_markers } }
        }
    }
}

url = "http://localhost:9200/yop/_search"
r = requests.get(url=url, data=json.dumps(q))
print(r.json())
```

I expect to get the documents

```
    {'N_timeend_epoch': 10, 'N_marker': True, 'N_hostip': 'A'},
    {'N_timeend_epoch': 10, 'N_marker': True, 'N_hostip': 'B'},
    {'N_timeend_epoch': 10, 'N_marker': False, 'N_hostip': 'A'},
```

The JSON (`json.dumps(q)`) which is built up above is

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "should":[
                  {
                     "query":{
                        "bool":{
                           "must":[
                              {
                                 "N_hostip":"A"
                              },
                              {
                                 "N_timeend_epoch":10
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "query":{
                        "bool":{
                           "must":[
                              {
                                 "N_hostip":"B"
                              },
                              {
                                 "N_timeend_epoch":10
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I do not understand how to combine `query` with `filter/filtered`. I tried to use `filter/filtered` just once to encompass all the queries, and several combinations of the schema but they all lead to the error

```
{u'status': 400, u'error': u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[bUIc4GtASg-1iFokFMwI8A][yop][0]: SearchParseException[[yop][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"should": [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "A"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}, {"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "B"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}]}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[yop] [_na] filter malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[bUIc4GtASg-1iFokFMwI8A][yop][1]: SearchParseException[[yop][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"should": [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "A"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}, {"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "B"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}]}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[yop] [_na] filter malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[bUIc4GtASg-1iFokFMwI8A][yop][2]: SearchParseException[[yop][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"should": [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "A"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}, {"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "B"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}]}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[yop] [_na] filter malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[bUIc4GtASg-1iFokFMwI8A][yop][3]: SearchParseException[[yop][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"should": [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "A"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}, {"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "B"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}]}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[yop] [_na] filter malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[bUIc4GtASg-1iFokFMwI8A][yop][4]: SearchParseException[[yop][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"should": [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "A"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}, {"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"N_hostip": "B"}, {"N_timeend_epoch": 10}]}}}}}]}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[yop] [_na] filter malformed, no field after start_object]; }]'}
```

How to correctly build such query?

Note: I initially added the `python` tag as my code is Python based but the issues is with the syntax of elasticsearch. Feel free to add it back if you feel that this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can go about this; I'll share one below. I used Elasticsearch 1.3.4.

First let me say, though, that if you haven't seen the [Sense plug-in](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en) for Chrome, you should check it out. The auto-complete helps a lot with sorting out complicated Elasticsearch syntax. At [Qbox](https://qbox.io/) we built a modified version that lets us share Elasticsearch code (sort of a combination of Sense and Github Gist, you might say). Here is some code I put together while working on your problem:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/095b574569026b6d80fdbb0f4a2f66c7de844b13

For the punchline look at the last code block, but here's the setup. I created the index with a mapping that specifies `"not_analyzed"` on the `"N_hostip"` field, so we don't have to worry about the tokens being changed to lower-case (this is a common problem people run into, since if you don't specify an analyzer the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used, and it converts tokens to all lower-case), then bulk indexed the documents you listed above:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/yop/"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/yop/" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "N_hostip": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "N_marker": {
               "type": "boolean"
            },
            "N_timeend_epoch": {
               "type": "long"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/yop/_bulk/" -d'
{"index": {"_index": "yop", "_type": "doc"}}
{"N_timeend_epoch": 10, "N_marker": true, "N_hostip": "A"}
{"index": {"_index": "yop", "_type": "doc"}}
{"N_timeend_epoch": 10, "N_marker": true, "N_hostip": "B"}
{"index": {"_index": "yop", "_type": "doc"}}
{"N_timeend_epoch": 11, "N_marker": true, "N_hostip": "A"}
{"index": {"_index": "yop", "_type": "doc"}}
{"N_timeend_epoch": 11, "N_marker": true, "N_hostip": "B"}
{"index": {"_index": "yop", "_type": "doc"}}
{"N_timeend_epoch": 10, "N_marker": false, "N_hostip": "A"}
{"index": {"_index": "yop", "_type": "doc"}}
{"N_timeend_epoch": 11, "N_marker": false, "N_hostip": "B"}
{"index": {"_index": "yop", "_type": "doc"}}
{"N_timeend_epoch": 11, "N_marker": false, "N_hostip": "B"}
'
```

Then I used Sense to help me walk through setting up the query (the autocomplete does a pretty good job of telling you which terms are allowed in which blocks, though it's not perfect). I used a top-level filter since it is a lot more efficient than a query, and a query is not needed here. Also note that I have an outer `should` containing two `must` clauses, each of which contain two `term` filters (if I hadn't used `not_analyzed` in the mapping, I would need to use `"N_hostip": "a"`, etc). So if a document matches either of the two clauses inside the `should`, it will be returned.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/yop/_search" -d'
{
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": [
                          { "term": { "N_hostip": "A" } },
                          { "term": { "N_timeend_epoch": 10 } }
                       ]
                   }
               },
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": [
                          { "term": { "N_hostip": "B" } },
                          { "term": { "N_timeend_epoch": 10 } }
                       ]
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

This returns what I think you are expecting. It should be straightforward to convert this to Python code (make sure you check out the [Python client](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/index.html), if you haven't yet).

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. Not only you gave the solution but your comment regarding `not_analyzed`clarified a lot in some of my previous searches (which did not work as I was searching for `B` in the example above, instead of `b`). Sense is also  excellent, better than the head plugin I was using. Thanks again.